# error al convertir DATE

Tags: jquery, sql, datatables, jquery-validate

estoy usando SQL server para crear una consulta para un reporte que me están solicitando, solo que tengo una situación, los campos de las fechas me lo da con un formato de fecha  USD y lo quiero cambiar a un formato usado en Mexico pero me esta mandado el siguiente error.

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

tengo estas variables que coloca el usuario

```
@FECHA_INICIO_PAGO DATETIME = '25-10-2021',@FECHA_FIN_PAGO DATETIME = '25-10-2021',@FECHA_INICIO_FACTURA DATETIME = '10-08-2021',@FECHA_FIN_FACTURA DATETIME = '10-08-2021',@TIPO_MONEDA VARCHAR(20)= 'MXN'
```

y esta es mi consulta

```html
select
--Accounting_v_AP_Invoice.Invoice_Link,
A.Invoice_No as Factura,
S.Supplier_Code as Codigo_Proveedor,
S.Name as Nombre_Proveedor,
D.Debit as Subtotal,
--D.Unit_Price AS 'Monto',
T.Tax_Amount as Total_IVA,--,
A.Amount as Total,
A.Currency_Code as Moneda,
A.Foreign_Currency_Amount as Total_moneda_origen,
A.Exchange_Rate_Date as Fecha_Tipo_Cambio,
A.Amount/NULLIF(A.Foreign_Currency_Amount,0) as Tipo_cambio,
A.Paid_Date as Fecha_Pago,
--Accounting_v_AP_Invoice.Exchange_Rate, 
CE.Exchange_Rate as Exchange_Rate,
A.Foreign_Currency_Amount/A.Exchange_Rate as Total_MXn,
T.Tax_Rate as IVA,
AA.Account_No as Cuenta,
A.Invoice_Date as Fecha_de_Factura,--Fecha de factura
A.Foreign_Currency_Amount/CE.Exchange_Rate as total_pago,
(A.Amount-T.Tax_Amount)/CE.Exchange_Rate as subtotal_pago,
T.Tax_Amount/CE.Exchange_Rate as total_iva_pago

from Accounting_v_AP_Invoice A

inner join Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_Dist_Tax T
on A.Invoice_Link = T.Invoice_Link

inner join Common_v_Supplier S
on A.Supplier_No = S.Supplier_No

inner join Common_v_Supplier_Accounting SA
on SA.Supplier_No = S.Supplier_No

inner join Accounting_v_Account AA
on AA.Account_Key = SA.AP_Credit_Account_Key

INNER JOIN Common_v_Currency_Exchange CE
ON CE.Date_Start = A.Expected_Pay_Date

inner join Common_v_Currency CC
on A.Currency_Code = CC.Currency_Code

LEFT JOIN Accounting_v_AP_Invoice_Dist D 
ON T.Invoice_Link = D.Invoice_Link AND T.Line_Item_No = D.Line_Item_No

where CONVERT (DATE,FORMAT(A.Paid_Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO_PAGO AND @FECHA_FIN_PAGO
AND @TIPO_MONEDA = CC.Currency_Code
AND CONVERT (DATE,FORMAT(A.Invoice_Date,  'dd/MM/yyyy')) BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO_FACTURA AND @FECHA_FIN_FACTURA AND A.Invoice_No = '1185'

ORDER BY S.Supplier_Code ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posible solución:

```
Select
--Accounting_v_AP_Invoice.Invoice_Link,
  a.invoice_no As factura
, s.supplier_code As codigo_proveedor
, s.name As nombre_proveedor
, d.debit As subtotal
--D.Unit_Price AS 'Monto',
, t.tax_amount As total_iva --,
, a.amount As total
, a.currency_code As moneda
, a.foreign_currency_amount As total_moneda_origen
, a.exchange_rate_date As fecha_tipo_cambio
, a.amount / NullIf(a.foreign_currency_amount, 0) As tipo_cambio
, Convert(varchar,a.paid_date,103) As fecha_pago
--Accounting_v_AP_Invoice.Exchange_Rate, 
, ce.exchange_rate As exchange_rate
, a.foreign_currency_amount / a.exchange_rate As total_mxn
, t.tax_rate As iva
, aa.account_no As cuenta
, Convert(varchar, a.invoice_date,103) As fecha_de_factura --Fecha de factura
, a.foreign_currency_amount / ce.exchange_rate As total_pago
, (a.amount - t.tax_amount) / ce.exchange_rate As subtotal_pago
, t.tax_amount / ce.exchange_rate As total_iva_pago
       From accounting_v_ap_invoice As a
            Inner Join accounting_v_ap_invoice_dist_tax As t On a.invoice_link = t.invoice_link
            Inner Join common_v_supplier As s On a.supplier_no = s.supplier_no
            Inner Join common_v_supplier_accounting As sa On sa.supplier_no = s.supplier_no
            Inner Join accounting_v_account As aa On aa.account_key = sa.ap_credit_account_key
            Inner Join common_v_currency_exchange As ce On ce.date_start = a.expected_pay_date
            Inner Join common_v_currency As cc On a.currency_code = cc.currency_code
            Left Join accounting_v_ap_invoice_dist As d On t.invoice_link = d.invoice_link And t.line_item_no = d.line_item_no
       Where a.paid_date Between @Fecha_Inicio_Pago And @Fecha_Fin_Pago 
       And @Tipo_Moneda = cc.currency_code 
       And a.invoice_date Between @Fecha_Inicio_Factura And @Fecha_Fin_Factura
       And a.invoice_no = '1185'
       Order By s.supplier_code Asc;
```

Los campos de tipo `datetime`, no tienen formato. Se almacenan en **binario**.

La salida de los mismos, si tiene un formato por defecto y es en la misma donde se aplican las funciones, para mostrar los datos, como queremos.

No utilices `Format` y luego `Convert`, porque con uno de los dos te sirve. `Convert` es mucho más rápido, aunque `Format` tiene más posibilidades.